# Is this a good approach to structure my models?

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

A little bit of info. I want the user to be able to view their feed which contains friends' posts, group posts, etc. I am using Django Rest Framework and providing this feed endpoint to a frontend.

My initial thought was just making separate models(tables) per items I needed. Like a `UserPost`, `GroupPost`, `EventPost`, but I feel when trying to consolidate the data it will just be doing a lot of joins and having to stitch together the data.

ex)

```
class UserPost(models.Model): # GroupPost, EventPost
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # group/event = models.ForeignKey(Group/Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This didn't seem like a good approach in case we wanted to add post type functionality for other models.

My other approach is using intermediate models. `Post` model is the base and `UserPost`, `GroupPost`, `EventPost` being the intermediate models having a OneToOne relationship to post and `GroupPost` would have a foreign key (OneToMany) relationship to a `Group` model.

ex)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserPost(UUID_PK, models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(
        Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name='_uPost', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='_groups')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class GroupPost(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(
        Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name='_gPost', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    invited = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='_events')

class EventPost(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(
        Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name='_ePost', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This approach isn't too bad, but it does require an extra query now.
Then to mimic getting a user's "feed" I would filter like this

```py
users = # friends
groups = # groups of the user
events = # events of the user

posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(created_by__in=users, _gPost__isnull=True, _ePost__isnull=True) | Q(
        _gPost__group__in=groups) | Q(_ePost__event__in=events)).distinct().select_related('created_by')

# _gPost__isnull=True and _ePost__isnull=True is exclude the other types of post and only get the "normal" posts.
```

which just looks awful.

I am unsure if this is a good enough approach or if anyone else has recommended for improving this.

I did look into GenericRelationship and wasn't sure if that would actually make this better. I have a few models that deal with GenericRelationship and for the most part, have been a bit of a pain.

Comment: This is a polymorphism problem, may I suggest you read this excellent [article](https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/)? Your various `Post` models seem to be undecided if they want to be polymorphic. They half-way implement an inheritance to `Post` but do not enforce it (`null=True`).

Comment: OK, cool thanks for the link. Having gone through it seems my best bet is Concrete Base Model or Generic Foreign Key. I have used GFK already and at times found it cumbersome to use, mainly with Django Rest Framework. It seems Concrete Base Model is good enough here. Though I will probably implement both and see how they are.